# Button invisble but enabled

Tags: android, eclipse

i designed my whole activity page in photoshop and opened it in eclipse.I want to put buttons on my fake image buttons. Doesnt it make any problem? I use the code below to make the button invisible but it disables button too. How can i fix this problem?

```
  android:visibility="invisible"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do like that (having a fake ImageButton on a View you want to make clickable), as many error can occur with doing it. Assuming you are trying to put this button on a whole ImageView, or a whole Layout, or at least a whole view, you should consider adding a click listener to this view. Try to find more information about how to use the [`View.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) method. You will have less error to debug with it.

But if you still want to do, try instead using [`android:alpha`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aalpha) property:

```
android:alpha="0"
```

It will make the button become invisible, but still present, and still active

This [`android:alpha`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aalpha) attribute allows you to specify an opacity value for a color.

Comment: kudos for answering the question ask asked.  However adding a "but you really should not be doing this" would be nice, too, because this approach is a hard-to-diagnose error waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I added more informations as you suggested !

Answer (score 1):

To be honest you shouldn't be doing that unless you are testing something or prototyping. Instead, you should cut your design in photoshop and export the images for your buttons.

Your approch will most likely cause the buttons to be positioned incorrectly above the image when run on different devices with different screen sizes.

The correct way to do this would be to use the `ImageButton` view with a `StateListDrawable` set as the source image.

You can read more about State Lists here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

It's very easy to declare it in XML and have different images for various button states (pressed, disabled, focused, ...).

To sum it all up. I would do the following things:

1. Export images for my buttons in all the different states that you prepared (i find neutral and pressed as an absolute minimum).
2. Import them as drawables in your project (be sure to generate different versions for every screen density you want to support).
3. Create a State List Drawable XML Resource as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).
4. Set the resource created in step 3 as the `android:src` property of your `ImageButton` (`setImageResource(int)`).

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:background="@null"` for your button. It will make that default gray background disappear, making your button invisible but still allowing you to add text etc if you want to.

That being said: I would not recomment a button here. I would prefer Pauls answer in your particular case.